# character vectorization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tokenize

I am trying to follow the Tensorflow Beginner Example to load text data by using "text_dataset_from_directory" and tokenize those data with "TextVectorization". (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification)

Is there any easy way to do character vectorization?

Comment: Why would you like to do character vectorization? There are only 26 unique alphabets. But not the case with text (string tokens).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a copy of char file and word file.

```
Example:
Char Version: I g o t o s c h o o l b y b u s
Word Version: I go to school by bus
```